# How to add rank based on points in mysql

Tags: mysql

I could use some assistance with this query.

Here's my table:

```
id      name    point
1       yogi      5
2       sasi     10
3       white     5
4       black     8
```

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM points ORDER BY point DESC
```

The result is:

```
id      name    point
 2      sasi      10
 4      black      8
 1      yogi       5
 3      white      5
```

But I'd like results like below. Please guide me.

```
id      name    point  rank
 2      sasi      10     1
 4      black      8     2
 1      yogi       5     3
 3      white      5     4
```

Is this possible to do?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
    FROM points ORDER BY point DESC
```

as a single line query like following

```
SELECT *, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank 
   FROM points, (SELECT @rank:=0) temp
   ORDER BY point DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the response its not working properly for me that was not my original query my query having 4 join tables. i dont know how to explain that here, that is why i posted small query. rank order coming like this 2,4,1,3.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    @rank:=@rank+1 'rank' FROM points, (select @rank:=0) r
ORDER BY 
    point DESC
```

Source : [Displaying row number (rownum) in MySQL](http://jimlife.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/)

Comment: Thanks for the response its not working properly for me that was not my original query my query having 4 join tables. i dont know how to explain that here, that is why i posted small query. rank order coming like this 2,4,1,3.

Comment: you should use some logic and adapt the same logic into your query.